# $.scrollTo not working in Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I made a simple WordPress site with a theme called OneEngine.

Here is a demo link: https://oneengine.enginethemes.com/

Interestingly, in Chrome the navigation does not appear to work.

I have pinpointed the piece of script responsible for scrolling.

```
// SCROLL TO
$('#main-menu-top a,ul.slicknav_nav li a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log('Click event');

    if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        return;

    $('#main-menu-top a').removeClass('active').css('border-bottom-color', 'none');

    $('ul.slicknav_nav li a').removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');

    if(this.hash == "#home")
        $.scrollTo(0,800);
    else
        $.scrollTo( this.hash, 800, {offset:-$(".sticky-wrapper").height()});

    var bgcolor = $(this.hash).find('span.line-title').css('backgroundColor');

    $(this).css('border-bottom-color', bgcolor);

    $('.slicknav_nav').hide('normal', function() {

        $(this).addClass('slicknav_hidden');

    });

    $('a.slicknav_btn').removeClass('slicknav_open').addClass('slicknav_collapsed');

    return false;
});

$("a#scroll_to").click(function(event) {
    $.scrollTo("#header", 800);
});
```

I'm confident that the part that isn't working is `$.scrollTo();`. Typing this into Google yielded `window.scrollTo` so I changed every instance to `window.scrollTo()` but this yielded jumpy anchors with no offset.

This section `offset:-$(".sticky-wrapper").height()` I know is roughly similar to:

`var stickyWrapperHeight = $(".sticky-wrapper").height()` (which is 76 pixels).

I can't actually find a native scrollTo method as described so I think it may, in fact, be JQuery scrollTo - https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

My biggest question would be why doesn't this work in Chrome?

I've seen potential alternatives such as the following:

```
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

        console.log($(".sticky-wrapper").height())

        var height = $(".sticky-wrapper").height();

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
```

Am I just using an outdated version of `scrollTo()`?

Comment: your site is in https but your favicon image is in http , it is blocked the content so try to change the image HTTP to HTTPS.  
this one
'http://    enginethemes.com/demo/oneengine/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/et-favicon.png check the chrome console.

Comment: press ctrl+U for page source and check the head links in chrome. you can change this image from admin->theme customize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if they have SSL problems on their demo page and that you get "$" is not a function if you don't type down jQuery() instead. I noticed that it still doesn't work even when you try to use the plugin right in the console.

The version of scrollTo they use in the theme is outdated and is also known not to work in recent versions of chrome :

https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/164

Try it with the latest version, it should work.

Otherwise if for some reason you can't update the plugin you can make it work using something like this :

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#skills").offset().top}, 'slow');
```

Comment: I've literally just seen the thread about the outdated version issue, thank you so much for your response. I was going crazy, started rebuilding everything and then saw the thread... :/

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Changed to scrollTo v2.2 and my site is now working again ok.