# scrollTo() and jquery scrollTop() not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am making a puzzle platformer using html elements as obstacles. Some levels I want to start at the bottom of the document. So I tried using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).height());
}
```

and

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

they both work perfectly fine in Firefox but neither work in Chrome. I only could get it to work when animating the scroll which will not work for what I am trying to do.

edit: I am not using jQuery.toScroll() I tried vanilla toScroll and jQuery.scrollTop()

Comment: Please add which jQuery and browser version you are experiencing the issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$.scrollTo not working in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273599/scrollto-not-working-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers attach their scrollbars to the page differently. Use $('html,body').scrollTop(). You should also use $(window).innerHeight(). Like this...

```js
$('html,body').scrollTop($(document).height() - $(window).innerHeight());

//Or to smooth scroll it

$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).innerHeight()
}, 1000);
```

Note: $(document).height() will return the same value as $(window).innerHeight() if the document is shorter than the window.

Comment: I found out the problem was I was using jQuery 2 :( I don't know why because all my other projects use the newest version. Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: I should also note that $(document).height() will return the same as $(window).innerHeight() if the document is shorter than the window. For your purposes it wouldn't matter as the goal is just to scroll to the bottom, and if the document is shorter than the window you'd already be at the bottom anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I did not execute full testing but I'm also experiencing the issue via Developer Tools at least on a specific jQuery version and latest Chrome. `animate` does work. `scrollTop` and `scrollTo` do both not work. Nonetheless even if you explicitly said that you not want to use animate I still recommend it as it is working and I see no reason of not using it if you use it like this:

`$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 500}, 0);`

This will scroll to 500px and has no animation at all because the duration is set to 0. I also have to point on a previous issue with Chrome:

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273599/scrollto-not-working-in-chrome)

[Issue on Github](https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo/issues/164)

I know the issue is closed but it might be relevant and probably it should be reported because there is something fishy.

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work when animate is set to 0, 0.1 seems to work but it doesn't seem very elegent

Comment: @Truce 0 does work, I tried it before I posted this answer, at least on the jQuery version I have tested it